# CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY parameter for xcodebuild (Xcode 4)

Tags: shell, ios4, xcode4, xcodebuild

I'm using `xcodebuild` utility shipped with Xcode 3 to automate my builds under Hudson. The command looks like it follows:

```
xcodebuild -project Project.xcodeproj -target Target -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]="iPhone Distribution:XXXXXX"
```

I'm trying to use the same command for Xcode 4 but it seems that `xcodebuild` just ignores `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY` parameter and signs with the provisioning profile which is selected for the target in Xcode.

It's a quite crucial for me since I have to sign build with 3-4 different profiles. It works OK with Xcode 3 but doesn't work with Xcode 4.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9):

A newer xcodebuild now allows settings to be specified.
Taken from [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html):

```
xcodebuild [-project projectname] [-target targetname ...]
           [-configuration configurationname] [-sdk [sdkfullpath | sdkname]]
           [buildaction ...] [setting=value ...] [-userdefault=value ...]
```

I also found this resource for explaining the [available settings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-DontLinkElementID_10)

```
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY (Code Signing Identity)
    Description: Identifier. Specifies the name of a code signing identity.
    Example value: iPhone Developer
```

However, PROVISIONING_PROFILE is missing from the index of available commands.

The command I finally used specified "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY" & "PROVISIONING_PROFILE" settings.

```
xcodebuild -sdk <iphoneos> -target <target_name> -configuration <Debug> CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Developer: Mister Smith" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="XXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX"
```

Comment: The argument of `PROVISIONING_PROFILE` must be UUID, such like `FAEB2AC2-33DB-4192-9711-06BD5ACD5ADD`.You could get this UUID from [iPhoneConfigUtility](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#iphone%20configuration%20utility) or just open .mobileprovision file with vim

Comment: or use `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print UUID" /dev/stdin <<< $(security cms -D -i pathtofile.provision)`

Answer (score 3):

I had following problem:

Our developers used the 'iPhone Development' signing identity, but I needed to use the 'iPhone Distribution' signing identity for our automated integration system.

So I added the line:

```
codesign -f --sign "iPhone Distribution: XXXXXXX" ${PATH_TO_APP}
```

between the `xcodebuild` and the `xcrun` commands to swap the code signing identities (see the `-f` flag).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know in Xcode 4 signing is done with `xcrun` tool:

```
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk "iphoneos" PackageApplication -v "myapp.app" -o "myapp.ipa" --sign "iPhone Developer: XXXXX" --embed "XXXXX.mobileprovisioning"
```

It is a bit uncomfortable to use because you must specify both your identity and mobileprovisioning file. Especially uncomfortable if you use last one from `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/` directory because its name is changed every time provisioning profiles are updated automatically from Provisioning Portal.

Comment: AFAIK to sign the app Xcode/xcodebuild uses /usr/bin/codesign application

Comment: Anyway did you solve the problem? I'm building my apps with this command.

Comment: @MishaKarpenko, the github link you shared is expired. can you share me the script again ? Thanks

Comment: @gstream79 Apologies as this project doesn't exist anymore. Are you experiencing problems with the `xcrun` call I've mentioned, or you're just trying to bring more convenience to your automation setup?

Comment: @MishaKarpenko, thanks for your update. I am trying to code sign for embedded swift framework but it requires to select certain certificates. But I want to do it with "Automatically manage signing". So I need to get selected certificate identity under "Automatically manage signing" checked. Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: @gstream79 Are you trying to do it in Xcode or in Terminal?

Comment: @MishaKarpenko, I've added script in project's Build phase for it in XCode.

Comment: @gstream79 Is it a 3rd party framework or the libswift one?

Answer (score 1):

Just use CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution:XXXXXX" with Xcode 4 (without [sdk=iphoneos*])

```
xcodebuild -project Project.xcodeproj -target Target -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution:XXXXXX"
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It just takes whatever is the default profile for the target/scheme.

Comment: Try to add PROVISIONING_PROFILE="$provision". It works fine for me when both (CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY & PROVISIONING_PROFILE are specified.

Comment: that's my complete command
`xcodebuild -target Target -sdk iphoneos -configuration "Ad Hoc" "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]==iPhone Distribution: XXX" "PROVISIONING_PROFILE=/Users/$USER/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/XXX.mobileprovision"` When xcodebuild is trying to sign the app it takes another profile. The one which is default for this scheme
`/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign "iPhone Distribution: XXX1" "--resource-rules=ResourceRules.plist" --entitlements "App.xcent" "App.app"` And XXX!=XXX1 unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I found a great workaround for building with jenkins.

Firstly, before setting up a job, download a jenkins plugin called:

Parameterized Trigger Plugin

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

Once you do that, create your job and while creating the job, select the

'This build is parameterized' checkbox

Create a String Parameter.  I call mine CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY.

So the name field in the String Parameter should be:

---

Name: CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY

Default Value: iPhone Developer: XXX XXXXX

Description: Whatever you want to put there

---

Then in your Xcode Plugin, find the 'Custom xcodebuild arguments' field.

In the Custom xcodebuild arguments field, place the following value:

CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=${CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY}

Finish setting up your job and you should be all set!

This will bypass the white space issue. The plugin is a life saver as it works wonderfully and you can customize your build with other parameters.